# How to solve $937=x^2+24x+24y+y^2$ where x and y are integers.

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the equation $937=x^2+24x+24y+y^2$, where x and y are integers. What I've tried is changing the right side of the equation to $$(x+y)^2-2xy+24x+24y$$
$$(x+y)^2-2(x+y)(-12)+xy$$
$$(x+y)((x+y)++24+x+y)$$
$$2(x+y)(x+12+y)$$

and then trying to find integers that fit into the equation but it doesn't seem like the most efficient or proper way to solve this equation.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: $(x+12)^2 + (y+12)^2 = ???$

Comment: When I evaluate that I get $$x^2+24x+24y+y^2+288$$. I'm not sure how that would help me solve the equation.

Comment: "Borrow" the 288 from your goal number 937 and see what's left. Then you're looking for sum of two squares to equal that, and there are various techniques for solving $u^2+v^2=m$ when it can be solved.

Comment: $937+288 = 1225 = 35^2 = (5\times 7)^2$, this reduce to the well known problem of writing a number as sum of squares...

Comment: I reduced it to $$649= (x+12)^2+(y+12)^2$$. How would I solve $$u^2 + v^2=m$$?

Comment: @coffeemath, I think you led OP astray. You should have told him to add $288$ to both sides of the equation.

Comment: when I add 288 to both sides then I get $$1225=(x+12)^2+(y+12)^2$$ Do I then just guess integer solutions, or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Using the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2+d^2) = (ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$, you can build up the solution (the non-trivial ones) you need from the little fact $5 = 2^2 + 1^2$. In the special case, $(a,b) = (c,d)$, the identity recues to $(a^2+b^2)^2 = (a^2-b^2)^2 + (2ab)^2$. This leads to $25 = (2^2-1)^2 + (2\cdot 2\cdot 1)^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$.

Comment: I'm so lost. I've never even heard of the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity. Are there any easier ways to solve this?

Comment: Could "try everything," not bad. Or use the fact that if $u^2+v^2$ is divisible by $7$ then $u$ and $v$ both are. (This is because $7$ is of the shape $4k+3$. So $x+12=7s$, $y+12=7t$ where $s^2+t^2=25$. That has solutions $s=0$, $t=\pm 5$, $s=\pm 5$, $t=0$ and $s=\pm 3$, $t=\pm 4$, and the other way around in all combinations.

Comment: @Lubin You're right, should have added the 288 to both sides, then the left side becomes the sum of squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete the square in each of the $x$ and $y$ quadratics:

$$\begin{align}
(x^2+24x+144)+(y^2+24y+144)=937+288&=1225 \\
(x+12)^2+(y+12)^2=35^2
\end{align}$$

So we are seeking Pythagorean triples where the triangle has two sides of length $x+12,y+12$ and a hypotenuse of $35$. Irreducible Pythagorean triples are of the form:

$$(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$$

The only primitive triples relevant here are those with $m^2+n^2\in\{5,7,35\}$ because these are all the factors of $35$ larger than one, and so are the only ones that can be scaled up to obtain a triangle with hypotenuse $35$.

The only one with integer solutions is $m^2+n^2=5 \implies m=2,n=1$ ($7$ and $35$ are of the form $4k+3$ so cannot be a sum of two integer squares) from which we have the primitive triple $(3,4,5)$. So

$$\begin{align}
&3^2+4^2=5^2 \\
&\implies 21^2+28^2=35^2 \\
&\implies (\pm21)^2+(\pm28)^2=35^2 \\
&\implies (x+12,y+12)\in\{(21,28),(-21,28),(21,-28),(-21,-28),(28,21),(-28,21),(28,-21),(-28,-21)\} \\
&\implies (x,y)\in\{(9,16),(-33,16),(9,-40),(-33,-40),(16,9),(-40,9),(16,-33),(-40,-33)\}
\end{align}$$

---

[Update]

As $\color{blue}{\text{coffeemath}}$ has pointed out, there are also trivial solutions (not Pythagorean triples) to the original equation, i.e.

$$(x+12,y+12)\in\{(\pm35,0),(0,\pm35)\}$$

whence

$$(x,y)\in\{(-47,-12),(23,-12),(-12,-47),(-12,23)\}$$

are also solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. It has inspired me to increase my knowledge on pythagorean triples.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you're inspired. It's a nice topic.

Comment: There are four more solutions $(x,y)=(-12,-12 \pm 35),(-12 \pm 35,-12).$

Comment: @coffeemath - Thanks - not sure how I missed *that*. I've updated the answer accordingly.